# Improve policy in Reinforcement learning?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

In model-free RL, we usually take two steps,one is value evaluation another is an improvement

the high-level description of algorithm is :

---

- sample data
- evaluate policy by Q iteration or SARSA iteration
- improve policy

---

my question is :

- What are the benefits of improving the policy after each step? do
  step 3 immediately after step 2.
- What are the benefits of updating the policy less frequently? do step
  3 after some iteration of step 2

I don't understand why to improve policy before getting true evaluation(that is improving after each step) is more popular. I find an intuition from RL textbook, but it's somewhat too vague.

The intuition is about GPI in Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto's book
page 87 , which says

> Each process drives the value function or policy
>   toward one of the lines representing a solution to
>   one of the two goals. The goals interact because the two lines are not orthogonal. Driving
>   directly toward one goal causes some movement away from the other goal

[image: About interation between evalution and improvement]

Comment: Could you link or describe the intuition you found (use [edit] to add details)? This is useful, because clearly you have already found an answer but it was not good. We need to know what it was you found in order to make a better answer.

Comment: ok,I have EDIT it